# Assigning function for button in angular

Tags: angular

I am working in angular. My problem is when the button type is "save" means it has to perform some function and if it is "update" means,it has to perform some function.

```
<button mat-flat-button color="primary" (click)="Editappaware info(drawer)" > 
  {{button type}}
</button>
```

Comment: <button mat-flat-button color="primary" (click)="Editappaware info(drawer)" >{{button type}}</button>

Comment: Please paste all relevant information in the question.

Answer (score 4):

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-button-8fpjmf?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

```
<button mat-flat-button color="primary" (click)="buttonType == 'save' ? save() : update()">{{buttonType}}</button>
```

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept this answer if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

```
<button mat-flat-button color="primary" (click)="onAction( buttonType )" >{{buttonType}}</button>
```

// in component.ts

```
onAction( type: 'save' | 'update'){
  type ==='save' ? create() : update();
}
```